# Where to legally buy Diablo 3 soundtrack?

Tags: diablo-iii

You can agree with me, Diablo 3 has an awesome soundtrack.

I've searched iTunes to buy it as an album, but it's not on there.

I've found some [good rips on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBF5FDBFF7A2EB549&feature=plcp), but here's the thing, I want to encourage the artists and am looking for a way to buy Diablo 3 OST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why it wouldn't have shown up in a search for you, but the soundtrack has been available on iTunes for a couple of days now:

http://itunes.apple.com/ca/album/id521963750

Comment: Oh dumb me, searching for Diablo 3 won't give you the album. I searched for Diablo Soundtrack and then it gave it right there.

Answer (score 1):

It should be available on iTunes, but it may depend on your country.

Source: http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/diablo-iii-soundtrack/id521963750